# _initp_misc_cfltcvt_tab and _FPinit when switching to /MDd

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, linker-errors

I switched my Visual C++ 2012 project from Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd). The project is a mixture of C++ .vcxproj and Intel Fortran (.vfproj) projects. After all is rebuild I get the errors below.

In CRT source code I see the offending symbols are defined in crt0dat.c if CRTDLL symbol is *not* defined. How do I make sure I get crt0dat with CRTDLL when compiling main application?

Any other suggestions how do I troubleshoot this?

```
50>cmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initp_misc_cfltcvt_tab referenced in function wWinMain
50>cmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FPinit
50>C:\spm\git\clones\SPM80_dll\MSBuild\x64\dll_debug\SPM_dll_debug_x64.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe /MDd builds require msvcrtd.lib.  This should be something that automatically gets linked into your project; it might be that it's ignored through a project setting.  Open the Project Settings for the C++ project and look under Linker->Input.  There are settings there for Ignore All Default Libraries and Ignore Specific Default Libraries.  See if there's anything there that might cause the linker to ignore msvcrtd.lib.

BTW, your code will also need the appropriate DLL to run, which for VS 2012 would be msvcr110d.dll.  This should already installed on your machine when you installed VS 2012, but it will have to be distributed with the executable if you move it to another computer.

Comment: You are correct, Mark, I can see msvcrtd.lib being linked. The unresolved symbols (_initp_misc_cfltcvt_tab) are actually in libcmt.lib. I build all my projects from source code and tripple-checked the runtime is Multi-threaded DLL everywhere. I'm looking for suggestions how to troubleshoot the unwanted _initp_misc_cfltcvt_tab dependency.